# StatefulBuilder VS StatefulWidget in Flutter - performance

Tags: flutter

We can use `StatefulBuilder` to update a specific element on the UI of a `StatelessWidget` and in other hand, we can archive similar result moving the `StatelessWidget` to a `StatefulWidget` and getting rid of the `StatefulBuilder` widget.

I prefer `StatefulBuilder` because it makes the code much easier and cleaner, but ***what's the best in terms of performance***?

**A**: Wrap everything on a `StatefulBuilder` using `StatelessWidget`

**B**: Use `StatefulWidget`

Comment: They are the same thing. StatefulBuilder is most of the time anti pattern though

Comment: what do you mean with "the same thing"? Definitely the have same result but the code is totally different. 
In my app I use a global state so I normally don't need to have `StatefulWidgets` at all. Only on some specific scenarios I need to update the UI without this global state and I don't want to have 2 `StatefullWidgets` vs 20 `StatelessWidgets`

Comment: They are identical. There's no different between them performance wize. StatefulBuilder _is_ a StatefulWidget after all.

Comment: Ok, got it. And why do you say `StatefulBuilder` is an anti pattern?

Comment: It could easily lead to a situation where your UI doesn't update after a change. You should use InheritedWidget instead.

Comment: But I don't need to pass data between widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is effectively no difference in performance between the two.  Both involve the creation of a State object.

Given that your using global state, there is no real reason to use a StatefulBuilder relating to part of that existing global state.  The StatefulBuilder provides a mechanism to have its own associated State object with state you define and can mutate.  In your case (global data), your state is already in memory, so you might as well just mutate it in your StatefulBuilder builder callback, e.g.

```
setState(() => myGlobalCounter.increment());
```

You are likely aware, that one would normally prefer an InheritedWidget based state solution.  While this can be considered equivalent in some ways to just moving global state to a global tree location, it more easily allows for all interested Widgets to be notified of changes to that state.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Would `InheritedWidget` be useful if I don't need any state from page1 on page2 but I do in page3? Because it sounds to me like something you need to use to display your state on every child widget.